# first child node name in xslt

Tags: xslt

I wanted to know how to find the first child node name of a specific node in xslt.

I have an xml:

```
 <name>
    <body>
      <para>
        <text> some text</text>
      </para>
    </body>
  </name>
```

Can i get a name using body/node()[1]/local-name()?

```
<xsl:template match="name">
<name> 
<xsl:variable name="firstchild" select="body/node()[1]/local-name()">
                        </xsl:variable>
 <xsl:value-of select="$firstchild" />
 </name>
</xsl:template>
```

The output should be

```
 <name>
    para
  </name>
```

Comment: Which element are you trying to display? And are you trying to display the name of the element, or the contents of the element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
<xsl:template match="name">
  <name>
  <xsl:variable name="firstchild" select="name(body/*[1])"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$firstchild" />
  </name>
</xsl:template>
```

Or if you don't actually need the variable, just simply...

```
<xsl:template match="name">
  <name>
  <xsl:value-of select="name(body/*[1])" />
  </name>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is an [xmlplayground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/fU9qol) of the 2nd example... to see the `<name>para</name>` click on the `View Source` in the output window.

Comment: This solution saved my many hours. Finding child elements with index fixed my problem. Thank you